# Compatibility with Facebook Share Link?

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink, share

I believe this is a problem with my forum board site.

If I'm trying to share a link from my forum board to my site, the link info/link thumbnail looks weird. No page title, no description, no thumbnail-nothing at all, only bad-looking link. Here's an screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEUg8.png

That's not the way it's supposed to show, right? Oddly, if I share a link from my main homepage (not from the forum board), it will display correctly. Like this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ekL3.png

The most weird thing is that only happens in my forum board. It's perfectly normal on my main site. Why does this happen? I once read meta tags and meta description affect this stuff, but my meta tags and meta description are fine...

**EDIT:**
I've just remembered. A few months ago (about early 2011) there's nothing wrong with my forum boards (the description appears properly). It's only recently (about March 2011) it starts to behave weirdly.

Comment: Odd. It shows, `Website inaccessible - The page at http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2140 could not be reached because the server returned status code 403.` It shows error. Why does this happen?

Comment: Are your message boards accessible without a login and from the United States?

Comment: Yup. My message board is accessible without a login. Though there are some member-only board, it's not supposed to appear like that (no description, no page title, etch), because I've tested it with another member-only message board (not my site), and it appears properly (page title and description exist).

Comment: I've just remembered. A few months ago (about early 2011) there's nothing wrong with my forum boards (the description appears properly). It's only recently (about March 2011) it starts to behave weirdly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB's share mechanism pulls a lot of data from your meta tags.  Make sure they're set right, e.g.,

```
<meta name="description" content="your_site_description_here">
```

FB also follows the opengraph protocol, so you can use that to set the images, etc that show up on the share window. (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), ex:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/your/site/image.jpg">
```

would make whatever image is at your/site/image.jpg show up when you hit the share button for that page.

EDIT:

On further investigation, the FB linter shows that your site returns a 403 forbidden, which means that it's filtering out FB's spider for not being in an approved IP list, or something similar.  This URL may contain some helpful info:  (http://www.invisionmodding.com/topic/47252-how-to-let-facebook-spider-to-visite-my-forum/)

Comment: Yup, I've set the meta tags right, but still it doesn't show up right... oddly, there's no problem with the main homepage, only the forum page

Comment: Is the page with the metatags accessible to Facebook's crawler? The URL linter ( developers.facebook.com/tools/lint ) will show you what Facebook gets when it tries to access your page, check you're allowing the crawler's user agent access your site, when I tried from a command line i was redirected and that URL you linked didn't load - i was redirected

Comment: Hmm. It seems pretty weird. When I tried http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1979 , it displays properly. So does with http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/ . But if it's some other pages, like this one: http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2152 , it's not displaying properly. What's wrong here?

Comment: Igy is right, the page is returning 403 forbidden to the FB linter, which means your forum software has some sort of filtering going on, probably against automatic crawlers.  Have you tried adding the FB spiders to the list of allowed visitors?  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this, as I'm not familiar with IPB, but I have included a link in my answer that may help.

Comment: Thanks for the link :) Anyway, about FB linter. It's quite weird; because I've tried http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/ , FB linter showed the page info properly. But for the other page, like http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2152 , it shows website inaccessible. Why does this happen?

Comment: Like I said, it might be something with your forum software.  Sometimes they'll come with stuff that will reject access to user agents + IPs they don't recognize, or user agents + IPs they mark as bots, to prevent people from stealing content on your site.  Most likely it is a setting you can change in your forum software somewhere.